# Доступ к Azure SQL с любого IP

Tags: sql-server, azure

По воле обучения нужно реализовать десктоп приложение и мобильное, оба обращаются к БД. Недолго думая подключил пробную подписку Azure. Поднял сервер и БД, добавил IP для доступа и всё вроде бы работает.

Только назрел такой вопрос: как получить доступ к бд, используя только логин и пароль, без проверки ip. Или это невозможно и Azure не подойдёт если я решу выложить это приложения для общего пользования?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доступ к `Azure SQL` регулируется правилами брандмауэра, где могут быть перечислены диапазоны адресов имеющие доступ к БД.
Указание следующего диапазона разрешит подключение с любого IP адреса:
`0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255`
 [Подробнее о способах управления брандмауэром](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure)